# Tableview will large and take place of hide of tapbar controlar

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my Project, I have a tableview and also a tab bar controller. In this project when i scroll the tableview, tabbar hides and tableview expands(becomes larger) with animation.
I have done in ios7 but it does not properly work in ios6. There appears a black bar all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the device version and set the size of your tableview height accordingly as:

```
#define isiOS7 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)



if (isiOS7) {
        NSLog(@"iOS7 or greater")

 } 
 else {
       NSLog(@"Less than iOS7");

 }
```

I guess this will fix that.

Alternately you can define your tableview height like this:

```
CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height - 50;//50 considering the height of the tabbar
CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: I also do this animation but it is working in ios 7 but in ios 6 , I check it that my table view increase and tab bar remove with animation  ly but there also present a black bar.